# React auth0 PrivateRouter combined with Redirect

Tags: reactjs, react-router, auth0

I'm new in react and I'm trying to do a simple page with logged section, to do that I've integrated Auth0 like this (https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-react-samples/blob/master/01-Login).

My problem comes when I'm trying to use PrivateRoute, currently my routes are being done like this

app.js does renderRoutes and receives the routes array.
My doubt is: How do I apply the PrivateRoutes to apply to all my dashboard components?

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    exact: true,
    component: () => <Redirect to="/app" />,
  },
  {
    path: '/auth',
    component: AuthLayout,
    routes: [
      {
        path: '/auth/login',
        exact: true,
        component: lazy(() => import('views/Login')),
      },
      {
        component: () => <Redirect to="/errors/error-404" />,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    route: '/app',
    component: DashboardLayout,
    routes: [
      {
        path: '/calendar',
        exact: true,
        component: lazy(() => import('views/Calendar'))
      },
      {
        component: () => <Redirect to="/errors/error-404" />,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    path: '/errors',
    component: ErrorLayout,
    routes: [
      {
        path: '/errors/error-401',
        exact: true,
        component: lazy(() => import('views/Error401')),
      },
      {
        path: '/errors/error-404',
        exact: true,
        component: lazy(() => import('views/Error404')),
      },
      {
        path: '/errors/error-500',
        exact: true,
        component: lazy(() => import('views/Error500')),
      },
      {
        component: () => <Redirect to="/errors/error-404" />,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

```
const Dashboard = props => {

  const { route } = props;

  const classes = useStyles();
  const [openNavBarMobile, setOpenNavBarMobile] = useState(false);

  const handleNavBarMobileOpen = () => {
    setOpenNavBarMobile(true);
  };

  const handleNavBarMobileClose = () => {
    setOpenNavBarMobile(false);
  };

  return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
          <TopBar
            className={classes.topBar}
            onOpenNavBarMobile={handleNavBarMobileOpen}
          />
          <div className={classes.container}>
            <NavBar
              className={classes.navBar}
              onMobileClose={handleNavBarMobileClose}
              openMobile={openNavBarMobile}
            />
            <main className={classes.content}>
              <Suspense fallback={<LinearProgress />}>
                {renderRoutes(route.routes)}
              </Suspense>
            </main>
          </div>
          <ChatBar />
          </div>
  );
};
```

````
  const { loading } = useAuth0();

   if (loading) {
    return <h1>loading</h1>
   }

  return (
        <StoreProvider store={store}>
          <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={MomentUtils}>
              <Router history={history}>
                <ScrollReset />
                <GoogleAnalytics />
                <CookiesNotification />
                {renderRoutes(routes)}
              </Router>
            </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
            </ThemeProvider>
          </StoreProvider>
  );
};```
````

Comment: How did you end up handling @colymore?

Comment: Finally, i've created a SessionComponent, it checks if it's logged, alowing acces, otherwhise redirect to login page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the same template that you're using before.

I implemented private routing like this.

Under AuthLayout component,
if it's logged in already, I redirect to dashboard component

Under DashboardLayout,
if it's not logged in, I redirect to '/auth'

Comment: you started with https://react-material-kit.devias.io/presentation, right?

Comment: Yep. That's it.

Comment: So did you ignore PrivateRouter compnents? Just check inside layout?

Comment: Would love to see an example @JikunL